# Base64 Encoding for file upload VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vba, file-upload, encoding, base64

I have a project in **VBA** that does the base64 encoding and uploads the file (.xlsm).

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const clOneMask = 16515072          '000000 111111 111111 111111
Private Const clTwoMask = 258048            '111111 000000 111111 111111
Private Const clThreeMask = 4032            '111111 111111 000000 111111
Private Const clFourMask = 63               '111111 111111 111111 000000

Private Const clHighMask = 16711680         '11111111 00000000 00000000
Private Const clMidMask = 65280             '00000000 11111111 00000000
Private Const clLowMask = 255               '00000000 00000000 11111111

Private Const cl2Exp18 = 262144             '2 to the 18th power
Private Const cl2Exp12 = 4096               '2 to the 12th
Private Const cl2Exp6 = 64                  '2 to the 6th
Private Const cl2Exp8 = 256                 '2 to the 8th
Private Const cl2Exp16 = 65536              '2 to the 16th

Private cbTransTo(63) As Byte
Private cbTransFrom(255) As Byte
Private clPowers8(255) As Long
Private clPowers16(255) As Long
Private clPowers6(63) As Long
Private clPowers12(63) As Long
Private clPowers18(63) As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim lTemp As Long

    For lTemp = 0 To 63                             'Fill the translation table.
        Select Case lTemp
            Case 0 To 25
                cbTransTo(lTemp) = 65 + lTemp       'A - Z
            Case 26 To 51
                cbTransTo(lTemp) = 71 + lTemp       'a - z
            Case 52 To 61
                cbTransTo(lTemp) = lTemp - 4        '1 - 0
            Case 62
                cbTransTo(lTemp) = 43               'Chr(43) = "+"
            Case 63
                cbTransTo(lTemp) = 47               'Chr(47) = "/"
        End Select
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 255                            'Fill the lookup tables.
        clPowers8(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp8
        clPowers16(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp16
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 63
        clPowers6(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp6
        clPowers12(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp12
        clPowers18(lTemp) = lTemp * cl2Exp18
    Next lTemp

    For lTemp = 0 To 255                            'Fill the translation table.
        Select Case lTemp
            Case 65 To 90
                cbTransFrom(lTemp) = lTemp - 65     'A - Z
            Case 97 To 122
                cbTransFrom(lTemp) = lTemp - 71     'a - z
            Case 48 To 57
                cbTransFrom(lTemp) = lTemp + 4      '1 - 0
            Case 43
                cbTransFrom(lTemp) = 62             'Chr(43) = "+"
            Case 47
                cbTransFrom(lTemp) = 63             'Chr(47) = "/"
        End Select
    Next lTemp

End Sub

Public Function Encode(sString As String) As String

    Dim bTrans(63) As Byte, bOut() As Byte, bIn() As Byte, lOutSize As Long
    Dim lChar As Long, lTrip As Long, iPad As Integer, lLen As Long, lTemp As Long, lPos As Long


    iPad = Len(sString) Mod 3                           'See if the length is divisible by 3
    If iPad Then                                        'If not, figure out the end pad and resize the input.
        iPad = 3 - iPad
        sString = sString & String(iPad, Chr(0))
    End If

    bIn = StrConv(sString, vbFromUnicode)               'Load the input string.
    lLen = ((UBound(bIn) + 1) \ 3) * 4                  'Length of resulting string.
    lTemp = lLen \ 72                                   'Added space for vbCrLfs.
    lOutSize = ((lTemp * 2) + lLen) - 1                 'Calculate the size of the output buffer.
    ReDim bOut(lOutSize)                                'Make the output buffer.

    lLen = 0                                            'Reusing this one, so reset it.

    For lChar = LBound(bIn) To UBound(bIn) Step 3
        lTrip = clPowers16(bIn(lChar)) + clPowers8(bIn(lChar + 1)) + bIn(lChar + 2)    'Combine the 3 bytes
        lTemp = lTrip And clOneMask                     'Mask for the first 6 bits
        bOut(lPos) = cbTransTo(lTemp \ cl2Exp18)        'Shift it down to the low 6 bits and get the value
        lTemp = lTrip And clTwoMask                     'Mask for the second set.
        bOut(lPos + 1) = cbTransTo(lTemp \ cl2Exp12)    'Shift it down and translate.
        lTemp = lTrip And clThreeMask                   'Mask for the third set.
        bOut(lPos + 2) = cbTransTo(lTemp \ cl2Exp6)     'Shift it down and translate.
        bOut(lPos + 3) = cbTransTo(lTrip And clFourMask) 'Mask for the low set.
        If lLen = 68 Then                               'Ready for a newline
            bOut(lPos + 4) = 13                         'Chr(13) = vbCr
            bOut(lPos + 5) = 10                         'Chr(10) = vbLf
            lLen = 0                                    'Reset the counter
            lPos = lPos + 6
        Else
            lLen = lLen + 4
            lPos = lPos + 4
        End If
    Next lChar

    If bOut(lOutSize) = 10 Then lOutSize = lOutSize - 2 'Shift the padding chars down if it ends with CrLf.

    If iPad = 1 Then                                    'Add the padding chars if any.
        bOut(lOutSize) = 61                             'Chr(61) = "="
    ElseIf iPad = 2 Then
        bOut(lOutSize) = 61
        bOut(lOutSize - 1) = 61
    End If

    Encode = StrConv(bOut, vbUnicode)                   'Convert back to a string and return it.

End Function
```

The generated output is exactly like this:
[Required Output](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)

I am trying to achieve the same output in VB.Net but I am unable to do so. I tried using the following:

```
Dim testStr As String = "test.xlsm"
Dim byt As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(testStr)
testStr = Convert.ToBase64String(byt)
```

Input String: http://txt.do/obff

But I am not getting exactly the same string back. The first line is different in both cases (VBA and VB.Net) and I'm not sure why.

**Required Output** (VBA and the weblink):

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCsmTVRbwEAAD8EAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

**Generated Output (VB.Net)**:

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA/PzVRbwEAAD8EAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCA/BAIoPwACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Could you please let me know where I am going wrong and how can I achieve the same in VB.Net?

Comment: what is the input string?

Comment: Its an excel file. (.xlsm) whose contents I read into a string using IO.FileStream function.

Comment: Do you want me to paste the code here?

Comment: Using a simple string of "Hello world" both of those methods give the same output "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=" so it must be something to do with the file encoding at a guess.

Comment: you can run various strings thru the Online converter linked to and see that they match the .NET B64 output.  IF your .NET version is not matching the handrolled VBA one, perhaps it is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by getting the file directly, reading all its bytes and converting it to base64 string.

```
Dim dat As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName)
testStr = Convert.ToBase64String(dat, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
```